# DAX expression equivalent to SQL's "in"

Tags: dax, ssas-tabular

Just starting out with DAX Expressions.

Is there an expression equivalent to SQL's "in" for DAX?

I'd like to do a check for participation on an arbitrary list of values.

For example, how would this translate into DAX?

```
    WHEN QueueNumber IN ('9127', '9409', '9415','9401','9427','5591','9405','8893','9430','9403','9404','9412','9429') THEN 'Member'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately, we don't have operator like "IN" in DAX.

you should write your code in this way:
    **QueueNumber='9127'|| QueueNumber='9409'||... **

for more information read this article:

https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/from-sql-to-dax-in-and-exists/

Answer (score 3):

Update for people who find themselves here. There is now (since late 2016) an IN operator in DAX.

Use before IN:

```
SmallMediumOrders :=
CALCULATE (
    [Orders],
    Products[Size] = "Small" || Products[Size] = "Medium"
)
```

Can now be written as:

```
SmallMediumOrders :=
CALCULATE (
    [Orders],
    Products[Size] IN { "Small", "Medium" }
)
```

For full list of DAX operators, see Microsoft's reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634237.aspx